# Can Sweepstakes Require a Survey to Enter?

Tags: united-states, internet, sweepstakes

In the USA, can sweepstakes require that users fill out a survey to enter? I understand that users obviously cannot be made to pay to enter but the concept of a mandatory survey seems less clear. Is this considered to be 'consideration'?

According to [TargetMarketingMag](http://www.targetmarketingmag.com/article/key-legal-compliance-considerations-before-administering-a-contest-sweepstakes/all/), special legal advice is necessary when

> a survey, questionnaire or repeat visits to a website or location are
>   required to enter the promotion.

Meanwhile, [RaffleCopter](http://blog.rafflecopter.com/2015/04/no-purchase-necessary-giveaways/) says that surveys are included in the definition of 'consideration':

> When you hear the word consideration, it’s referring to [...] or
>   engaging in activities that require a considerable amount of time
>   (like filling out an in-depth survey for example or making multiple
>   in-store visits).

So are surveys always a form of consideration? What constitutes if a survey is 'in depth' or not?

It seems to me that there are scenarios in which it is legal. For example, in order to enter the Alaska Airlines Sweepstakes, their [rules](https://survey.alaskalistens.com/company_res/alaskalistens/survey/officialrules/OfficialRules.html?v=20160126) state:

> 6. To enter the Sweepstakes, complete the survey at
>      www.alaskalistens.com

Thus, my question is when is it legal to ask for a survey entry that *is* mandatory?

Answer (score 1):

Consideration in a contract is the *obligatory* giving something of value in return for something of value.

Objectively, the sweepstakes ticket is valuable and so is the data in a survey. If the completion of the survey is *required* this this makes it a raffle, not a sweepstakes. You can ask someone to complete an *optional* survey providing they get the ticket either way. You can also collect data that is *necessary* to give effect to the sweepstake such as contact details even though these have value.

Comment: Wouldn't this make the (likely legal) Alaska Airlines 'sweepstakes' I referenced in the updated copy of my question illegal?